# php unset multidimensional array element which key value is match

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1201
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1200
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1196
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1193
        )
)
```

and I want to remove array which values are match with `property_id`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1201
    [1] => 1200
    [2] => 1193
)
```

and I want this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1196
        )
)
```

I am sharing my code for what i have done:

```
for($b=0; $b<count($beBounceResults); $b++){
    $beBounceProID[] = $beBounceResults[$b]->property_id;
}
// Getting thus array in this variable $beBounceProID
Array
(
    [0] => 1201
    [1] => 1200
    [2] => 1193
)

$counter = "0";
foreach ($results as $key => $value){
    if($results[$key]->property_id == $beBounceProID[$counter]){
        unset($results[$key]);
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

but after that I am getting `Notice: Undefined offset:`

Any idea what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: instead of $counter = "0"; use $counter = 0;

Comment: You have 1193 in your list, but still want to keep it?!

Comment: @anantkumarsingh This makes no difference! Absolutely wrong, if it 's index 0 it will cast it implicit to an int

Comment: Sorry guys its my mistake. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
foreach ($results as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($results[$key]->property_id , $beBounceProID) )
    {
        unset($results[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fast and simple to understand +1

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is just to filter the arrays which you don't want out like this:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($v)use($property_id){
    return !in_array($v->property_id, $property_id);
});
```